# child div not taking the whole dimensions

Tags: html, css

I have a problem making a child div taking the whole width and height even if I make it 100% in width and height as shown in the code bellow

```
<div id="images_rows">
    <div class="img_item"><div><span>Gone Fishing</span></div></div>
    <div class="img_item"><div><span>By the sea</span></div></div>
    <div class="img_item"><div><span>The great valley</span></div></div>
    <div class="img_item"><div><span>A night to remember</span></div></div>
    <div class="img_item"><div><span>On the lake</span></div></div>
    <div class="img_item"><div><span>On the mountains</span></div></div>
    <div class="img_item"><div><span>Take a flight</span></div></div>
    <div class="img_item"><div><span>going to the forest</span></div></div>
</div>
```

The CSS is as the following :

```
div#images_rows {
    font-size: 0;
}
div.img_item {
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 799px;
    margin:0;
    height: 270px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
div.img_item > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    background-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
    font-family: lovelo;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 200ms cubic-bezier(0.15,0.75,0.5,1);
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.img_item > div:hover {
    background-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0);
    background-size: 110%;
}
div.img_item > div > span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

and this is the artifact I am having :

[image]

and this is the result in the browser as shown in inspect element:

- **That's the Parent div :**

[image]

- **And this is the child div :**

[image]

And as we can see there are some floating numbers because of percentage style of the parent div, and the child doesn't take the whole width the floating numbers which leaves a space not covered

Is there any ideas how this problem can be solved ?

Comment: Use Flexbox for that

Comment: @OverCoder it's not backward compatible, some old browsers does not support flexbox,

Comment: try write united between parent `div`tag. ex: `<div class="img_item"><div><span>Gone Fishing</span></div></div><div class="img_item">`...

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) SO question.

Comment: Yes that's right. but [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) says 97% of browsers running in the world support Flexbox

Comment: @PeterMader that's alredy has taken care of, the issue is not a space between inline-block elements, read the question carefully

Comment: @OverCoder Yes I know, but it is a mandatory thing for me to use the classic oldschool way
more than that some browsers are still buggy concerning this Flexbox, even Edge is still buggy what concerns the alignment

Comment: What browser are you using? Moreover can you setup a JSFiddle?

Comment: @OverCoder this is the JSfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/z9hjxb6c/
and for the borwsers, I'm not using only one browser, I test my code in all known browsers